# Difference between migrateuser and adduser manually

Tags: 2007, active-directory, user, migrate

Just want to clarify what will be the difference between the two:

1. I migrate a user 'xyz' from one AD domain e.g, DomainA\xyz to another AD Domain, DomainB\xyz using stsadm -o migrateuser cmdlet
2. if i just manually add 'xyz' user to new AD Domain, DomainB\xyz and the same xyz user also exist in old AD Domain, DomainA\xyz

whats will be the difference with user 'xyz' added manually and migrated through stsadm cmdlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrate user updates the reference in the User Information List to make sure the existing items refer to the correct migrated user in New Domain. So created by, modified by and all other user fields will work correctly in Migrate user command.

If you add a new user, it will be a new user for SharePoint; a new entry will be added in User Information List and no reference will be updated.